# "Send" code within a Send Message template

Tags: html, css

For many I'm sure, this is an easy fix but I've tried looking into it and to be quite honest, my knowledge of coding isn't like many of you. Having said that, I've downloaded a free template and I've been able to clean things up, make it my own except for one thing. When folks want to reach me, they add their name, number, email and message in the proper fields but when they hit "Send", I want their message and info to be sent to my email address. Can you please explain how this is done? I've attached the link so you can view.

http://landonmusicgroup.com/web3/contact.html#

Many thanks!
CL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, first u should note that sending email needs backend management, so first you should grap all form data, then should submit a form, and finally in backend u should check submitted data and execute sending email process

Comment: I truly appreciate your response. Thank you, but this is far to complex for me to understand. What is the simplest way one can explain? For me, the simplest is "go into this file, replace or add this code, etc. Being that it is sent to my email address, this can't really be difficult. Cheers!